# JsonMappingException while accessing REST endpoint

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to access a REST end point using jersey client. This end point accepts formParams and response should be JSON format. While accessing the rest endpoint I am getting below error

**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class javax.ws.rs.core.Form and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )**

My REST service accept formParam and queryParam parameter . To invoke REST endpoint via client I am using below code. form is a instance of Form which has form parameters .

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        client.register(LogFilter.class);
 WebTarget wr= client.target(getTarget());
     wr = setPath(wr, paths);
        return wr.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .post(Entity.form(form), Response.class);
```

Any idea what could be reason of such error ?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question. LogFilter was trying to write convert Form Entities into Json string hence the error .
Only commenting out that filter , resolved the issue.